# Update xml attributes with LINQ to XML

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<URUN id="1" uName="KT-08" thumb="images_/berjer_/small_/17.jpg" image="images_/berjer_/17.jpg" desc="" />     
<URUN id="2" uName="KT-08" thumb="images_/berjer_/small_/18.jpg" image="images_/berjer_/18.jpg" desc="" />       
<URUN id="3" uName="KT-08" thumb="images_/berjer_/small_/19.jpg" image="images_/berjer_/19.jpg" desc="" />
<URUN id="4" uName="KT-08" thumb="images_/berjer_/small_/20.jpg" image="images_/berjer_/20.jpg" desc="" />
```

After remove an element for ex: id=1;and after that it's like id=2,id=3 id=4. My problem is i want to update XML like id=1 id=2 and id=3. How can i do that?

Comment: I think you're missing some of your sample XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking...

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var e in elem.Elements("URUN")) {
  e.SetAttributeValue("id", i);
  i++;
}
```

This assumes that you have already removed the first URUN element (with id=1) and you want to update the rest to have sequential IDs starting at 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement urunlur = XDocument.Load("filepath.xml").Root;
var uruns = urunlur.Elements("URUN");

//the next line will throw an exception if 
//  (a) a URUN element exists without an id attribute
//  (b) there is no URUN element with an id = 1
//  (c) a URUN element exists with a non-integer id

uruns.Single(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value) == 1).Remove();

var count = uruns.Count();
var sorted = uruns.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("id").Value);
for(int i = 0; i<count;i++)
{
    sorted.ElementAt(i).SetAttributeValue("id",i+1);
}
```